# check if current object is clicked object for multi level list

Tags: jquery

im trying to make a multi level expandable list (with 3 levels) in jquery myself.
whenever a level is expanded, i want all the other expandable lists, which are not parents of the clicked item, to collapse. unfortunately i dont manage to make that happen, whenever i click on a second-level menu item, not only all other menus collapse, but also the parent of the clicked item (so i cannot see the third level menu of the clicked element).

here my code

```js
$(".expandable a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //check if the clicked item is an expandable
  if ($(this).parent('li').hasClass("expandable")) {
    //check if anmation still running
    if (!$(this).next('ul').is(':animated')) {
      //check if is expanded already or not
      if ($(this).next('ul').is(":visible") == true) {
        //hide content
        $(this).next('ul').slideUp(200, function() {
          // Animation complete.
        });
      } else {
        var clicked_obj = $(this);

        //hide all other contents
        $(".expandable a").each(function(index) {

          //check if current object is child of the clicked object, in that case dont collapse
          if ($(this).find('.expandable').find('a').is(clicked_obj)) {
            //dont collapse this one
          } else {
            $(this).next('ul').slideUp(200, function() {
              // Animation complete.
            });
          }
        });
        //show content
        $(this).next('ul').slideDown(200, function() {
          // Animation complete.
        });
      };
    };
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">

  <li>
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw list-icon"></i>Overview</a>
  </li>
  <li class="expandable">
    <a><i class="fa fa-file fa-fw list-icon"></i>Files<i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
    <ul class="nav">

      <li>
        <a href="">Second level Link</a>
      </li>

      <li class="expandable">
        <a href="">Second level menu<i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li>
            <a href="">Third Level Link</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">Third Level Link<</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-user-plus list-icon"></i>User Requests</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw list-icon"></i>Statistics</a>
  </li>
  <li class="admin_menu expandable">
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw list-icon"></i>Administration<i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>
        <a href="">Second Level Link</a>
      </li>

      <li class="expandable">
        <a href="">Second Level Menu<i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li>
            <a href="">Third Level Link<</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">Third Level Link<</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

the code works, except of this "if":

```
//check if current object is child of the clicked object, in that case dont collapse
if ($(this).find('.expandable').find('a').is(clicked_obj)){...
```

i hope somebody can help me make my menu work properly..
thanks in advance!

Comment: You can just use `if ($(this).contains(clicked_object))`

Comment: Actually, the correct syntax is `if ($.contains(this, clicked_object))`

Comment: thanks for your answer! but since jacqbus' answer i feel motivated to go the short-code way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best code is the shortest one so i made this in another way. This universal code works for as many levels as you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function (){

// Hide all expandables menus at start
$('.expandable ul').hide();

// When click on .expandable > a element
$('.expandable > a').click(function(e) {
 
 // Close all expandable, excluding current parents and siblings
 $('.expandable ul')
  .not($(this).parents('ul'))
  .not($(this).siblings('ul'))
  .stop(true,true)
  .slideUp();

 // Toggle current submenu
 $(this)
  .next('ul')
  .stop(true,true)
  .slideToggle();
 
 return false;
}); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">

  <li>
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw list-icon"></i>Overview</a>
  </li>
  <li class="expandable">
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-file fa-fw list-icon"></i>Files<i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
    <ul class="nav">

      <li>
        <a href="">Second level Link</a>
      </li>

      <li class="expandable">
        <a href="">Second level menu<i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li>
            <a href="">Third Level Link</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">Third Level Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-user-plus list-icon"></i>User Requests</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw list-icon"></i>Statistics</a>
  </li>
  <li class="admin_menu expandable">
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw list-icon"></i>Administration<i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>
        <a href="">Second Level Link</a>
      </li>

      <li class="expandable">
        <a href="">Second Level Menu<i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li>
            <a href="">Third Level Link</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">Third Level Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i dont really trust that code since its so short and i cant fully understand it, but it works very well, so thanks a lot! but thats always the thing with someone else writing code for me: i fail to change a thing in it if i didnt make it myself. unfortunately expanded menu items dont collapse when i click on them a second time. so i HAVE to make a "is visible" check at some point, right?

Comment: solved it this way: if ($(this).children('ul').is(":visible") == true) {
   $(this).children('ul').stop().slideUp();
  } else {
   $(this).children('ul').stop().slideDown();
  }  but i'd be really interested how you would have done that since it feels like reading your coding increases my skills dramatically

Comment: OK i made this code even shorter and better, because using stopPropagation() [may give unpleasant consequences](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/). Now it's so simple, i think you can understand it. Also it resolve another problem with toggling submenu.